# 'fell to' meaning in The Hobbit

Tags: meaning

In J.R.R. Tolkien's The Hobbit, on page 129, I found an unfamiliar to me use of the phrase "fell to."

> Then suddenly the trap-doors **fell to** with a boom and their voices
> faded away.

Here are the meanings of "fall to" that I found in my vocabulary:

> fall to ()  1) (adverb) to begin some activity, as eating, working, or
> fighting  2) (preposition) to devolve on (a person) the task fell to
> me  3) - fall to the ground

None of them seem to fit.

So, my question is, why did Tolkien use 'fell to' instead of just fell, like this:

> Then suddenly the trap-doors **fell** with a boom and their voices faded
> away.

Is there a subtle difference that warrants the use of "fell to" instead of just "fell"?

Comment: They fell **closed**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use 'to' after an verb of action, sound, etc, involving a door, when that action or sound closes the door or accompanies its closing. When a door **slams to**, **falls to**, **bangs to**, **crashes to**, or is **pushed to**, then it becomes closed.

> to
>
> adverb   **mainly UK**
>
> into a closed position:
>
> *I'll just push the door to*.

[To (adverb) Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

In this case it is simply a literal fall. The trap-doors dropped shut.

I usually think of trap doors as falling open, as in"The gallows door fell open to the condemned prisoner's doom" but it certainly works the other way as well.

Comment: The question is asking us to say whether **fell to** means something different than simply **fell**.